# How can I get lines of dialogue in quotes using Python or regex?

Tags: python, regex

I've tried a few of the answers on this site with no luck. Here's an example of the kind of text I'm working with:

> "But if you have got them to-day," said Elizabeth, "my mother's
>   purpose will be answered."
>
> She did at last extort from her father an acknowledgment that the
>   horses were engaged. Jane was therefore obliged to go on horseback,
>   and her mother attended her to the door with many cheerful prognostics
>   of a bad day. Her hopes were answered; Jane had not been gone long
>   before it rained hard. Her sisters were uneasy for her, but her mother
>   was delighted. The rain continued the whole evening without
>   intermission; Jane certainly could not come back.
>
> "This was a lucky idea of mine, indeed!" said Mrs. Bennet more than
>   once, as if the credit of making it rain were all her own. Till the
>   next morning, however, she was not aware of all the felicity of her
>   contrivance. Breakfast was scarcely over when a servant from
>   Netherfield brought the following note for Elizabeth:
>
> "MY DEAREST LIZZY,--
>
> "I find myself very unwell this morning, which, I suppose, is to be
>   imputed to my getting wet through yesterday. My kind friends will not
>   hear of my returning till I am better. They insist also on my seeing
>   Mr. Jones--therefore do not be alarmed if you should hear of his
>   having been to me--and, excepting a sore throat and headache, there is
>   not much the matter with me.--Yours, etc."
>
> "Well, my dear," said Mr. Bennet, when Elizabeth had read the note
>   aloud, "if your daughter should have a dangerous fit of illness--if
>   she should die, it would be a comfort to know that it was all in
>   pursuit of Mr. Bingley, and under your orders."
>
> "Oh! I am not afraid of her dying. People do not die of little
>   trifling colds. She will be taken good care of. As long as she stays
>   there, it is all very well. I would go and see her if I could have the
>   carriage."

From this example I'd like to extract

```
"But if you have got them to-day, my mother's purpose will be answered"
"This was a lucky idea of mine, indeed!" 
"MY DEAREST LIZZY,-- I find myself very unwell this morning, which, I suppose, is to be imputed to my getting wet through yesterday. My kind friends will not hear of my returning till I am better. They insist also on my seeing Mr. Jones--therefore do not be alarmed if you should hear of his having been to me--and, excepting a sore throat and headache, there is not much the matter with me.--Yours, etc." 
"Well, my dear,"
```

... and so forth. The rule I'm trying to get into regex is

```
1. get all strings within a " " (there can be multiple on the same line)
2. if the line ends with a \n before finding a second ", continue grabbing the next line so long as it also begins with a "
```

Comment: @Emma ideally yes

Comment: so you want to replace that extra space or new line in out with single space  ?

Comment: @CodeManiac ideally have that group of text be on the same line, as depicted

Comment: What i will suggest is `"(?:(^\s*")|([^"]))+?"` this  will give you all your matches and than from the matches you can remove multiple space to single space to get output in same line [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VUKCXe/1/)

Answer (score 1):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/Eo2aFw/2) might help you to achieve that. It would divide your text into three groups:

```
(\")(.*)(\")
```

[image]

If you wish to pass `\n`, you might simply add it to the second group using an OR `|`, and [update it as](https://regex101.com/r/x1TTpl/1):

```
 (\")(.*|\n)(\")
```

[image]

Comment: This will not fullfill the second condition mate, `"MY DEAREST LIZZY,-- I find mys.....` this line

Comment: @Emma thanks! but this also includes text like 'said Mr. Bennet, when Elizabeth had read the note aloud'

Comment: @neptune do you want `MY DEAREST LIZZY,-- I find mys...` to be in output ? if not please update in question as well

Answer (score 1):

It might not what you are looking for, but you can try this one: [RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/8O3ZCa/1)

```
text = '''
"But if you have got them to-day," said Elizabeth, "my mother's purpose will be answered."

She did at last extort from her father an acknowledgment that the horses were engaged. Jane was therefore obliged to go on horseback, and her mother attended her to the door with many cheerful prognostics of a bad day. Her hopes were answered; Jane had not been gone long before it rained hard. Her sisters were uneasy for her, but her mother was delighted. The rain continued the whole evening without intermission; Jane certainly could not come back.

"This was a lucky idea of mine, indeed!" said Mrs. Bennet more than once, as if the credit of making it rain were all her own. Till the next morning, however, she was not aware of all the felicity of her contrivance. Breakfast was scarcely over when a servant from Netherfield brought the following note for Elizabeth:

"MY DEAREST LIZZY,--

"I find myself very unwell this morning, which, I suppose, is to be imputed to my getting wet through yesterday. My kind friends will not hear of my returning till I am better. They insist also on my seeing Mr. Jones--therefore do not be alarmed if you should hear of his having been to me--and, excepting a sore throat and headache, there is not much the matter with me.--Yours, etc."

"Well, my dear," said Mr. Bennet, when Elizabeth had read the note aloud, "if your daughter should have a dangerous fit of illness--if she should die, it would be a comfort to know that it was all in pursuit of Mr. Bingley, and under your orders."

"Oh! I am not afraid of her dying. People do not die of little trifling colds. She will be taken good care of. As long as she stays there, it is all very well. I would go and see her if I could have the carriage."
'''

talk = re.findall(r'\"([^\"]+?)(\"|\-\-\n)',text)
for t in talk:
    print(t[0])
```

Comment: this definitely matches the sample! thank you. however, when I try it on the full text, it breaks on this:

Mr. Darcy's letter to Lady Catherine was in a different style; and still
different from either was what Mr. Bennet sent to Mr. Collins, in reply
to his last.

"DEAR SIR,

"I must trouble you once more for congratulations. Elizabeth will soon
be the wife of Mr. Darcy. Console Lady Catherine as well as you can.
But, if I were you, I would stand by the nephew. He has more to give.

"Yours sincerely, etc."

Comment: Show me your text that gives you the error. I made the regex based on your sample.

Comment: Please provide only the chapter that gives you the error.

Comment: I think it is very complex since the texts are inconsistent. But if the problem happens only once, you can make an exception. Change the regex to: `\"([^\"]+?)(\"|\-\-\n|\-\-Yours ever)`. [UpdatedRegex](https://regex101.com/r/SAHYaJ/4)

Answer (score 0):

For your example data, you might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
"[^\n"]*"|"[^\n"]*\n+"[^"]*"
```

- `"[^\n"]*"` Match from opening till closing double quote without matching a newline
- `|` Or
- `"[^\n"]*\n+"[^"]*"` Match from opening quote till closing quote only when the first newline starts with a double quote

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Derrt1/1)